# PHP split the content of text area and insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I need to know how to do the following using php coding please

1. take inserted text from a textarea
2. split the content per line
3. Insert each line into the database as its own row with own id number

Can anyone show me how to do this please?

thanks

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_***

THis is what I have tried so Far

```
$is_first = true;


foreach (explode('\n', $_POST['code']) as &$voucher) {

    if ($is_first) $is_first = false; else $query .= ', ';

    $query .= '(' . mysql_real_escape($voucher) . ')';
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO back_codes (`code_id`, `code`) VALUES (NULL, "$voucher")');
}
```

Comment: What is specifically the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: have edited main field for what tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Refer to it using `$_POST['field_name']`, if it has been sent with POST request, like that:

   ```
   $textarea_value = $_POST['my_textarea'];
   ```
2. You can split strings using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), like that:

   ```
   $lines = explode("\n", $textarea_value);
   ```
3. Iterate through result of `explode()` and then insert rows one-by-one to the database.

   ```
   foreach ($lines as $line) {
       // $line here is a string
       // build a query based on it and execute it
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you sent data from textarea by submitting POST form data.
Let's say you textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea name="data"></textarea>
```

Then in PHP you can use following code:

```
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
  $line_data = explode("\n", $_POST["data"]);
  foreach($line_data as $key => $value)
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (col) VALUE('{$value}')";
 mysql_query($sql);
}
}
```